# What is wrong with the data that I am trying to send to matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following script:

```
import pandas
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

while True:
    data = [int(x) for x in raw_input("Enter the list containing the data: ").split()]
    letter_counts = Counter(data)
    df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(letter_counts, orient="index")
    df.plot(kind="bar")
    plt.show()
```

When I either type or copy and paste a series or numbers, for instance,

```
 1 4 5 6 3
```

the script works perfectly and shows me the histogram. However, when I paste numbers from the output I get from a different terminal window, for instance:

```
  13 13 16 16 16 16 9 9 9 9 9 15 15 15 15 20 20 20 20 20 22 22 22 22 13
  13 13 13 12 12 12 12 12 16 16 16 16 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
  15 15 22 22 22 22 22 15 15 15 15 13 13 13 13 13 18 18 18 18 10 10 10
  10 12 12 12 12 12 10 10 10 10 20 20 20 20 20 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15
  17 17 17 17 17 13
```

The first time I enter the data, it works perfectly; however, when I enter it the *second* time, it doesn't do anything and then I have to hit enter again. It shows me the plot, but when I close it, it gives me the following error:

```
> Enter the list containing the data: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "make_histo.py", line 9, in <module>
>     df.plot(kind="bar")   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py",
> line 2627, in __call__
>     sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py",
> line 1869, in plot_frame
>     **kwds)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py",
> line 1694, in _plot
>     plot_obj.generate()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py",
> line 243, in generate
>     self._compute_plot_data()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py",
> line 352, in _compute_plot_data
>     'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__)) 
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the data you input have a linebreak in it? From the question it seems so; hence you would end up with several plots, one for each line.

Comment: make sure your data are numeric (i.e., not strings)

Comment: It doesn't seem like it. When I print the value of `letter_counts`, this is what I get:
`Enter the list containing the data: 13 13 16 16 16 16 9 9 9 9 9 15 15 15 15 20 20 20 20 20 22 22 22 22 13 13 13 13 12 12 12 12 12 16 16 16 16 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 22 22 22 22 22 15 15 15 15 13 13 13 13 13 18 18 18 18 10 10 10 10 12 12 12 12 12 10 10 10 10 20 20 20 20 20 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 17 17 17 17 17 13
Counter({15: 29, 13: 12, 12: 10, 20: 10, 22: 9, 10: 8, 16: 8, 9: 5, 17: 5, 18: 4})

`

Comment: The second time:

`Enter the list containing the data: 13 13 16 16 16 16 9 9 9 9 9 15 15 15 15 20 20 20 20 20 22 22 22 22 13 13 13 13 12 12 12 12 12 16 16 16 16 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 22 22 22 22 22 15 15 15 15 13 13 13 13 13 18 18 18 18 10 10 10 10 12 12 12 12 12 10 10 10 10 20 20 20 20 20 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 17 17 17 17 17 13

Counter({15: 29, 13: 12, 12: 10, 20: 10, 22: 9, 10: 8, 16: 8, 9: 5, 17: 5, 18: 4})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get the behavior you described: when I copy-paste the block of numbers from your question I get embedded line breaks and this causes raw_input() to get called multiple times.

A possible workaround for that problem is to make the program treat an empty line as end-of-input: the following very simple code accepts a copy-paste of your block of numbers OK on my system (Windows, Python 2.7):

```
while True:
    print ("Enter the list containing the data: ")
    lines = []
    while True:
        line = raw_input()
        if (line):
            lines.append(line.lstrip().strip())
        else:
            break
    data = []
    for line in lines:
        for x in line.split():
            data.append(int(x))
    print data
```

Hope this may be helpful.